# How do I call a function at start in Expressjs/nodejs (Setup method)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want my worker server to pickup tasks from parent server immediately after it starts and keep pinging for pending tasks.

Given that Nodejs is a event driven, how do I make my express server make a rest call to server and start working immediately after start?

In a way, I am asking for setup method in Nodejs.

Answer (score 6):

You have your `server.js` file (the one you call `node server.js` on).

Simply place whatever code you need to run at bootstrap there.

```
var express = require("express");
...

yourSetupFunction();

app.listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type of tasks you fetch from parent node. So I'm assuming you just want to know when the new server is ready to use and perform actions based on that.

The express documentation mentions about [app.listen](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen) as a function that can be configured.

Here's the code block

```
app.listen = function(){
    var server = http.createServer(this);
    //yourBootstrap();
    return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```